# Microsoft Unity XML configuration for Interception

Tags: unity-container

I've been trying to configure interception for Unity (I want to log to log4net before and after object method calls).

I've used this example:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/UnityAOPNHibernate.aspx

and its similar to this answer:

[Microsoft Unity - code to xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640806/microsoft-unity-code-to-xml)

but I get "Unrecognized element 'extensionConfig'." - on the line where it does GetSection("unity") below.

```
        IUnityContainer unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
        var configurationSection = 
          (UnityConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity")
```

Please help

Comment: I've figured it out, the xml schema changed in 2.0. If you look at the pdf for the documentation: http://unity.codeplex.com/releases/view/31277
then its clear you have to update the config to use the new schema for interception.

Comment: you should put this comment as an answer or delete the question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a section extention for this to work

```
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
<sectionExtension type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.Configuration.InterceptionConfigurationExtension, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Interception.Configuration"/>
...
```

Refer page 60 of [Unity20.PDF for the documentation](http://unity.codeplex.com/releases/view/31277#DownloadId=177468)